# How do I repeat a word using recursion in C?

Tags: c, recursion, cpu-word, repeat

This is a homework assignment but I'm stuck with an incorrect output. The assignment is to repeat the word 's', an 'n' amount of times using recursion. I don't know if I'm missing something obvious or that I'm on the wrong track. Here's my code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* repeat(char* s,int n){
    int len = strlen(s);
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(n*len*sizeof(char));
    if(n == 1){
        strcpy(temp,s);
        return (temp);
    }
    else{
        //temp = (char*)realloc(temp, n*len*sizeof(char));
        return (strcat(temp, repeat(s, n-1)));
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char* s = repeat("string", 3);
    printf("Result: "); fflush(stdout);
    puts(s);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The output I get is: Result: Ø
QèQstring

while it is supposed to be stringstringstring

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: When `n != 1` you run `strcat` on `temp` without initializing it. Maybe you want to hoist `strcpy(temp, s);` out from the `if`.

Comment: examine your arguments to strcat - it might be helpful to print them out before you call it...

Comment: your malloc makes no sense. You need to malloc the number of characters in the string + 1 (for the null terminating character), not `n*strlen(s)`.

Comment: The paramater is s, the word I want to repeat could be any word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *repeat(char *s, int n){
    int len = strlen(s);
    char *temp;
    if(n == 1){
        temp = malloc(len + 1);
        memcpy(temp, s, len + 1);
        return temp;
    }
    temp = repeat(s, n-1);
    temp = realloc(temp, n * len + 1);
    memcpy(temp + (n-1)*len, temp, len + 1);
    return temp;
}

int main(void) {
    char* s = repeat("string", 3);
    printf("Result: "); fflush(stdout);
    puts(s);
    free(s);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

---

```
//Simplification
char *repeat(char *s, int n){
    if(n == 0){
        return NULL;
    }
    int len = strlen(s);
    char *temp = realloc(repeat(s, n-1), n * len + 1);
    memcpy(temp + (n-1)*len, s, len + 1);
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are overcomplicating it. Just do this:

```
void repeat(char* s,int n){
    printf("%s", s);
    if(n > 1)
        repeat(s, n-1);
}

int main(void) {
     printf("Result: ");
     repeat("string", 3);
     fflush(stdout);
     return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that the `temp` you are applying `strcat` to is not initialized. The `temp` in the last recursion step is another one freshly allocated and used in the second parameter of `strcat`.

Beside this as already remarked the buffer is too small.

Rough suggestion for an alternative solution (untested)

```
// a recursively called function
char* repeat_rec(char* dest, char* s,int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        strcpy(dest, s);
        return dest;
    }
    else{
        return strcat(repeat_rec(dest, s, n-1), s);
    }
}
// a main part containing initialization (avoids too many allocs)
char* repeat(char* s,int n) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    char* dest = (char*)malloc((n*len + 1)*sizeof(char));
    return repeat_rec(dest, s, n);
}
```

Comment: If the purpose is just to print out then Red Alert's solution is more elegant. If the purpose is to allocate and create a buffer containing the string then this solution is ok...

Comment: 7.21.3.1 The strcat function 2. _If copying takes place between
objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined._

Comment: duh... @BLUEPIXY fully correct, thanks for noticing this. I modified now the code to avoid the overlap...

Comment: @jdehaan `len` is not defined. Perhaps you meant `strlen(s)`.